# Как подключить к проекту на golang ssl сертификат и использовать https?

Tags: golang, https, ssl

Как подключить к проекту на golang ssl сертификат и использовать https ?
Где можно бесплатно получить сертификат и как вообще с ними работать?, а то я этим ещё не занимался

Comment: у вас в вопросе подняты две не связанные друг с другом темы. вопрос про сертификаты уже и здесь неоднократно обсуждался: его можно сгенерировать самостоятельно без чьего-либо содействия абсолютно бесплатно, то есть даром.

Answer (score 1):

Ну проекты на golang редко выставляют наружу напрямую. Обычно проксируют через nginx или другой проксисервер. Все настройки https уходят туда.

http://nginx.org/ru/docs/beginners_guide.html - тут как насроить прокси
http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html - тут как настроить ssl

Как получить сертификат миллион статей. Бесплатно можно получить, например, тут https://www.startssl.com/ Они же выдадут все нужные инструкции во время получения.